# Javascript array object Output

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Can anybody help me I am new to javascript. I am not able to understand the below line of code. I spend hours to debug this code but I am not able to rectify.

```
var data = [
    {"name":"123123123123"},
    {"name":"123123123124"},
    {"name":"123123123125"},
    {"name":"123123123126"}
];
var x1 = {}
var basicS = {
    "question":[]
}
data.forEach(function(val,i){
   x1[val.name]=basicS;
});

console.log(x1);
data.forEach(function(val,i){
 x1[val.name].question.push('insert');
});
console.log(x1);
```

Output:

```
{
 123123123123:{
    question:[
      0:"insert"
      1:"insert"
      2:"insert"
      3:"insert"
    ]
},
123123123124:{
    question:[
      0:"insert"
      1:"insert"
      2:"insert"
      3:"insert"
    ]
},
123123123125:{
    question:[
      0:"insert"
      1:"insert"
      2:"insert"
      3:"insert"
    ]
},
123123123126:{
    question:[
      0:"insert"
      1:"insert"
      2:"insert"
      3:"insert"
    ]
}
}
```

Expected Output should be:

```
{
  123123123123:{
    question:[
      0:"insert"
    ]
},
123123123124:{
    question:[
      0:"insert"
    ]
},
123123123125:{
    question:[
      0:"insert"
              ]
},
123123123126:{
    question:[
      0:"insert"
    ]
}
}
```

Not able to understand from where four values are inserted inside the each question array while i am inserting only  one in each question 
array object.

Is there any alternative to solve this type of prblem.

Please help me out. I am totally confused. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you expect the result to look like? It's not at all clear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: `x1[val.name]` is pointing to the same `basicS` object. So in each iteration you are basically inserting values in the same object. Object assignment in javascript are reference only that means during assignments object reference will be assigned instead of a new copy of object

Comment: what do you want it to look like?

Comment: @JLRishe you can see the expected output now.

Comment: Thanks @abhishekkannojia i got my answer.

Comment: @Arrow I updated the expected output.

Comment: why people are down voting my question? i asked the valid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to create multiple objects:

```
data.forEach(function(val,i){
   x1[val.name]={
      "question":[]
    };
});
```

Or both loops in one O(n) instead of O(2n):

```
data.forEach(function(val,i){
   (x1[val.name]=x1[val.name] || {question:[]}).question.push(val);
});
```

Comment: @Mohut Bhagwani youre welcome;) feel free to hit the green checkmark somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because every value in `x1` is referencing the *same* `basicS` array. So you are pushing `insert` into that array four times.

To avoid this, give each item in `x1` a new array:

```js
var data = [
    {"name":"123123123123"},
    {"name":"123123123124"},
    {"name":"123123123125"},
    {"name":"123123123126"}
];
var x1 = {}

data.forEach(function(val,i){
   x1[val.name]= { "question": [] };
});

data.forEach(function(val,i){
 x1[val.name].question.push('insert');
});
console.log(x1);
```

Or, depending on what you're ultimately trying to do, you could just populate the arrays with their initial value instead of looping twice:

```js
var data = [
    {"name":"123123123123"},
    {"name":"123123123124"},
    {"name":"123123123125"},
    {"name":"123123123126"}
];
var x1 = {}

data.forEach(function(val,i){
   x1[val.name] = { "question": ["insert"] };
});

console.log(x1);
```

Comment: Thanks @JLRishe. for pointing out my mistake.Actually insert is just a sample I have to insert lot of questions which is coming from the API.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple.

Use a new object as your container to populate.
Switch from "forEach" to "for" loop to avoid confusion.
Create a new instance of the array on every iteration for reference.
Assign index at 0 to insert.Take object at iteration and set it the name property value.
Then assign to an Object with the question property set to your array at key '0'

```js
var data = [{
    "name": "123123123123"
  },
  {
    "name": "123123123124"
  },
  {
    "name": "123123123125"
  },
  {
    "name": "123123123126"
  }
];

var obj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

  var insert = [];
  
  insert['0'] = 'insert';
  
  obj[data[i].name] = {
    question: insert
  }
  
};

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks @Arrow for the answer. Advice Taken.